# Modifying an HTML Element through a JS Class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, dom

When defining a method on a user defined class that includes an HTML element JS throws a TypeError saying object.method is not a function.

My hunch is when only returning `document.createElement` the class inherits HTML object methods that prevent user defined methods from working? So my thought was to contain the HTML object as an element within an array, but still no dice.

```
class inputBox {
    constructor(attributeList){
        let element = document.createElement('input')
        //just creating a unique ID here
        attributeList.id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16);
        for (let attr in attributeList){
            this[attr] = attributeList[attr]
            element.setAttribute(attr,this[attr])
        }
        return [element,attributeList]
    };

    updateValue(newValue) {
        let element = document.querySelector(`#${this[1].id}`)
        return element.value = newValue
    };
}
```

this works fine

```
document.body.appendChild(inputBox1[0])
```

this not so much (note: there is no [0] since I'm querying the DOM)

```
inputBox1.updateValue("hello")
```

The idea is you could call something like the following with multiple parameters
`var inputBox1 = new inputBox({type:'email', placeholder:'Your email'})`

I think this is achievable with jquery, but was attempting a vanilla approach as learning exercise. Thx

Comment: `throws a TypeError saying object.method is not a function.` What exactly is the error? You do not have `object` or `method` in the code there

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you explicitly return an object from a constructor, the return value will be *just that object*, and not an instance of the class. When you do

```
return [element,attributeList]
```

what is returned is just a plain array, without anything connected to an `inputBox`, so proceeding to reference an `inputBox` class method on that array won't work.

Instead, put the `element` and `attributeList` onto the instance.

By putting the element onto the instance, you can also avoid creating a dynamic unique ID for each element (which is a code smell) - rather, just reference the `this.element`:

```
class inputBox {
    constructor(attributeList){
        this.element = document.createElement('input');
        this.attributeList = attributeList;
        for (const attr in attributeList){
            this.element.setAttribute(attr,this.attributeList[attr]);
        }
    }

    updateValue(newValue) {
        this.element.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

Still, unless there's going to be more code in the `inputBox`, there doesn't seem to be any use of the class here - after construction, its only exposed functionality is to set the value of the input, which could be done less obscurely by just using a reference to the input. Consider having a function that assigns the `attributeList` to the element's attributes, and then just using the plain element, eg:

```
const myInput = assignAttributes(attributeList);
// ...
myInput.value = 'newValue';
```

Comment: `this` makes sense, thx, and I agree with your latter suggestion, that’s where I started. My thought was the class could be useful for combing multiple operations, on multiple instances into a single method.